# How can I export 360 degree image to Google Map Street View

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

How can I upload a 360 degree image to Google map street view. (I know to take 360 degree photo and upload from street view app).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app) on how to upload photos using `curl`.

> Creating a photo requires three separate calls. The first call will return an upload URL, which is used in the second call to upload the photo bytes. After the photo bytes are uploaded, the third call uploads the metadata of the photo and returns the photo ID.

1. Request an Upload URL

   ```
   $ curl --request POST \
   --url 'https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo:startUpload?key=YOUR_API_KEY' \
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
   --header 'Content-Length: 0'
   ```
2. Upload the photo bytes to the Upload URL

   ```
   $ curl --request POST \
   --url 'UPLOAD_URL' \
   --upload-file 'PATH_TO_FILE' \
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
   ```
3. Upload the metadata of the photo

   ```
   $ curl --request POST \
   --url 'https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo?key=YOUR_API_KEY' \
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   --data '{
             "uploadReference":
             {
               "uploadUrl": "UPLOAD_URL"
             },
             "pose":
              {
                "heading": 105.0,
                "latLngPair":
                {
                  "latitude": 46.7512623,
                  "longitude": -121.9376983
                }
             },
             "captureTime":
             {
               "seconds": 1483202694
             },
           }'
   ```

There are also [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/libraries) available which you may use to avoid the need to manually set up HTTP requests and parse the responses.